# Unable to access the form data in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am actually new to ASP.NET and am unable to get the post data from form.
This is how my form looks

```
@page
@model IndianPoliticalData.Pages.UserCredentials.RegisterModel

<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Enter Username</label>
        <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username"/>

        <input type="hidden" value="insert" />
        
        <label>Enter Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

        <label>Enter Username</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have also created a store procedure which looks like this

```
create procedure spPolitical_specific_data_query
(
@Action varchar(10),
@username varchar(50),
@password varchar(50),
@email varchar(50)
)
as
begin 
If @Action='Insert'
Begin
Insert into UserData(username, password, emailId) values (@username, @password, @email)
end
else if @Action='View'
Begin
select * from UserData
End
End
```

And I am trying to add the data inserted to the database by running the following code.

```
public string newQuery = "spPolitical_specific_data";
        public QueryData()
        {   
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Database");
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(newQuery, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", What should I input overhere)
            

        }
```

How do I write the data entered, like `Request.Form["username"]`. How do you access it in asp.net

Comment: what is your question? Is Request.Form not working? How your controller looks like?

Comment: [Take a look at the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form)

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar I am making a razor page application and in this line ```cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", username)``` overhere I have written username just as a placeholder, instead there has to be the username that the user enters. So what is the syntax for that.

Comment: @Crowcoder okay i'll check it